# log4cplusud.lib missing when building with VisualStudio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, log4cplus

i already have a complete VS Solution (that is working on other systems) and i am trying to get it to build on my computer aswell.

The program is using log4cplus to (obviously) log - i already included the needed files, but when building VS tells me, that `log4cplusUD.lib` is missing. When searching through log4cplus i only found `log4cplusS.lib` and `log4cplusD.lib`

Does somebody know how to get this library or how to adjust VS to accept the other libraries? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please share more details about your question. Ex: log4cplus version, vc version and etc.. ANd also incude error message.

Comment: I'm getting the `LNK1104: cannot open file log4cplusud.lib` Error - That of course means, that VS can't either open or find this file, which is correct, since i can't find it either. I'm running log4cplus 1.1.3.

Comment: What profile did you choose to build Debug or Release or anything etc? , how did obtain the log4cplus lib, did you build it from scratch ? or get binaries from somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and i suppose you are using an already given folder containing the log4cplus data. Try to build it again and then you'll hopefully find the file. That solved it for me.

Comment: I indeed was given a folder containing the log4cplus data. Building it on my own fixed my problem, thanks!